# SetValue GetValue Javascript ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I've tried `document.getElementById('seTotalPayment').value` to set Spin Edit value but when i run web browser console it says `undefined`, so i tried this `var totalPay = document.getElementById('seTotalPayment_I');` and it works when i set value `totalPay.value = 10000`

So, i have `document.getElementById('seTotalPayment_I').value`

`"10000"`

But when i run this on console
`seTotalPayment.GetValue()`

the output is `0`

How to set spin edit if i run this code `seTotalPayment.GetValue()` the value is `"10000"`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found my own solution.
Just add hidden value to client-side and add `seTotalPayment.SetValue(document.getElementById('hfTotalValue').value);`
on my javascript